# Is a kernel classified as hardware or software?

Tags: kernel

I'm trouble shooting a phone issue for my boss and I've run into an unlocked bootloader. Which is a common sign of a rooted android device. But digging more into what makes a phone rooted and how to fix it. I've come into learning about OS,kernel and bootloaders. From what I understand an OS is in short how your device runs and manages it's memory it is stored and maintained in a kernel but is loaded from a set of instructions from a bootloader.

If I'm wrong with my description please let me know and I will edit it.

But is a kernel considered hardware?(Like a processor or ram)
Or software? (Application, IDE)
Or some hybrid of both?

And does the meaning of a kernel to a computer differ from the meaning of a kernel in Android?

Comment: Why you don't google it ? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(operating_system)

Comment: Can you physically touch a kernel? Answering this question should answer your question.

Comment: @DarkDust that's what confuses me. I am trying to understand if it is physical or if it is software that also lives in the processor.

Comment: @Ben-J I read that link but being a computer program that lives in the OS at it's center does that make it physically part of the processor? Like a specific pin that corresponds to the kernel or not? I know this seems like a dumb question and it probably is. I am just trying to understand.

Comment: First line of the wikipedia page : "The kernel is a computer program", so it is software!

Comment: Read the _first sentence_ of the linked Wikipedia article and think about what just that sentence is saying. Really, it's very obvious. Another hint: the kernel does not "live" in the processor.

Comment: OK thanks, maybe I just read it wrong. thanks for clarifying for me.

Answer (score 0):

> "in a kernel but is loaded from a set of instructions from a bootloader"

As you have said, a kernel is loaded into memory by a boot loader. In general, instructions that get loaded into memory to make a computer do something can be viewed as "software". You can't physically remove a boot loader from a phone or a computer, which makes it an abstract "thing" residing on the physical hardware, which is another way to view software.

> But is a kernel considered hardware?(Like a processor or ram) Or software? (Application, IDE) Or some hybrid of both?

You can view the kernel as a part of an operating system. An example would be Android, which uses a Linux based kernel, and windows 10, which runs on a windows NT kernel.

> And does the meaning of a kernel to a computer differ from the meaning of a kernel in Android?

Since a kernel is a part of the operating system, I assume you're talking about an OS like Windows by "computer". Yes, the kernels used in mobile and desktop operating systems serve the same purpose, which is to provide an interface between the software and hardware components of a computer system. This interface helps developers create software more efficiently via. different abstraction mechanisms.